# Can keycloak standalone deployment migrated to keycloak cluster?

Tags: keycloak, high-availability, keycloak-services

I have an instance running of keycloak. Can I upgrade it to cluster mode?

Comment: to provide an answer that will help you have to provide more information about your deployment. mostly how do you host your keycloak (e.g. kubernetes, openshift, standalone ,... )

Comment: currently in local environment